# writeCharacteristic error on Redmi or Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, xiaomi, redmi-device

I make an app that read and write some chars in BLE.

My operation are there:

- connect to gatt
- discover service
- read char
- write char

Everything is ok on each device except that for some xiaomi and redmi device.
I have a problem on writeCharacteristic, i dont have a response and device don't write nothing on LE periph.
After read a characteristics (so into "onCharacteristicRead" callback)
I call a write

```
final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicBadge = mBluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID_CHARSBADGE);
characteristicBadge.setValue(resultBadge); //resultBadge is an array
characteristicBadge.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicBadge);
```

but i don't have any response, onCharacteristicWrite is never called.
I tried everything, connectGatt with autoconnection or not.

Is there anyone with the same problem? I'll be crazy soon..

Comment: Does writeCharacteristic return true? Do you make sure you don't have any other outstanding GATT operation at the same time?

Comment: @Emil yes return true. And i am sure a don't have any operation at the same time..I'm stuck